Help to identify SOT23-3 code 'PF'
I suspect there is a defective SOT23-3 transistor code 'PF' in my refrigerator panel display (stopped working)
This SOT23-3 'PF' code is connected to 13V power and fed by another SOT23-3 transistor code 'NF'
Attached photo with sketch that I created by PCBA inspection
I don't how to identify the 'PF' code part number - search in the WEB yielded many options
Any support will be appreciated

From the Turuta SMD-codes Databook, an SOT-23 device with code PF is likely a PNP transistor, of type KRA106S. If the symbol next to the "PF" is a dash, then this could also be a dual Zener diode, the BZB84-C27.


Thanks
I saw these 2 options, but I think they don't fit to the wiring diagram
To me it looks like more MOSFET transistor switching the main voltage power

@AmiCohen The KRA106S is what's called a "digital transistor"; it has a series base resistor integrated in the same package, so it doesn't need an external resistor and the schematic would look similar to one using a PMOS.

Possibly KRA106S from Korea Electronics Co. Ltd.


+1 NF would then probably be KRC106S which has a picture on LCSC that shows similar markings.
